# Solving a non-homogenous recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve the following non-homogeneous recurrence relation i.e. trying to find $x_t$:

$$x_{t+1}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)x_t+\frac{t}{n}$$

My attempt: By writing the first few terms of the sequence $\{x_t\}_{t\geq 1}$, we see that

$$x_4=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^4x_0+\frac{1}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2+\frac{2}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{3}{n}$$

and hence:

$$x_t=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^tx_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{t-2}\frac{k}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{t-1-k}+\frac{t-1}{n}$$

So I am having trouble finding the second term $\sum_{k=1}^{t-2}\frac{k}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{t-1-k}$. Any ideas?

Comment: $$x_t=x_0 \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{t-1}+n \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^t-n+t$$

Comment: @Raffaele Thanks, did you happen to use the second term I have up there?

Comment: No. I used *Mathematica* command RSolve, like this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RSolve%5Bx%5Bt+%2B+1%5D+%3D%3D+%281+-+1%2Fn%29+x%5Bt%5D+%2B+t%2Fn%2C+x%5Bt%5D%2C+t%5D

Comment: As is often the case, introducing $x'_t:=x_{t+1}-x_t$ is helpful. We have $$x'_t=x_{t+1}-x_t=(1-1/n)x_t+t/n-(1-1/n)x_{t-1}-(t-1)/n = (1-1/n)x'_{t-1}+1/n.$$ If we want, we can eliminate the $1/n$ by repeating this via $x''_t=x'_{t+1}-x'_t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For notational convenience, I'll write

$$x_{t+1}=ax_t+(1-a)t.$$

The non-homogeneous equation has the obvious solution

$$x_t=ca^t.$$

Then we try the ansatz

$$x_t=pt+q,$$ which gives

$$p(t+1)+q=a(pt+q)+(1-a)t$$ and by identification

$$x_t=t+\frac1{a-1}.$$

Hence the general solution

$$x_t=t+\frac1{a-1}+ca^t.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x_{t+1}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)x_t+\frac{t}{n} \tag1$$

We want to find $a, b$ such that

$$x_{t+1} - a(t+1)-b =\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) (x_t-at-b) \tag2$$

Combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ and solve for $a, b$, we get

$$a=1, b=-n$$

Hence

$$x_{t+1} - (t+1)+n =\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) (x_t-t+n) \tag3$$

This means $\{x_t-t+n\}$ is a geometric sequence. Can you end it now?